# unity gone and cannot be reinstalled?

Tags: unity

help.unity got uninstalled after I used ppa purge to delete a repository when i use synaptic to install it it says:

```
`unity:
 Depends: libglib2.0-bin but it is not going to be installed
```

help`

Comment: Thats helped you ?

Comment: nope.afraid not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal and paste these lines one by one and try again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Hope that helps .

Comment: no man it is like this after the 3rd step                      The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 unity : Depends: libglib2.0-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, this is what you would want to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-bin
sudo apt-get install unity
```

This should forcefully install the required dependency. If that does not work, please post the error it prompts in your question.