# No interface, no Terminal

Tags: unity, command-line, virtualbox, 13.04, gui

I just rebooted my computer and have no interface (except my desktop background and desktop files), which means no unity and no notification bar.

Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't work.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, does however.

If anyone has a clue, I would be very grateful! I *really* want to get into Ubuntu, but it feels so fragile and easy to break :(

Answer (score 7):

I used Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get into TTY1, logged in with my username and password, and then typed :

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

It rapidly removed Virtualbox which i had just installed. Seems Virtualbox was behind the issue.

`sudo reboot` and i was ready to go again.

Thank you @Radu for your help.

Now I just have to figure out why Virtualbox broke ubuntu in the first place ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I also wonder what broke everything by me...

Answer (score 0):

Go in tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), login with your username and password and run this comands: that reset compiz and unity:

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
sudo unity --reset-icons &disown
```

After these, restart your system and should work like a charm:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Radu.
When i entered `sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`, i got the following :
    error: Error spawning command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=bcb228c2cbf598e4c9caa47c517c5caa -- binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process existed with code 1  
    
    Usage:  
    dconf reset [-f] PATH  
    
    Reset a key or dir. -f is required for dirs.  
    
    Arguments :  
    PATH  
    KEY  
    DIR

Comment: And then for the second line it says `unity: command not found`.

Comment: Then this should help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195633/unity-gone-and-cannot-be-reinstalled

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work because no internet connection. It seems even the WIFI is deactivated. I'm going to try plugging the ethernet in.